# Graph the following function $f(x) = \frac{x + 3}{x^2 -4}$

Tags: calculus

I have been able to calculate the Intercepts, Asymptotes, Local Max/Min but when finding the inflection points, I can't seem to factor my derivative if you could kindly help that would be great.

First Derivative: $$\frac{-x^2-6x-4}{(x^2-4)^2}$$

Second Derivative: *If I'm right* $$\frac{4x[x^3+9x^2+4x-12]}{(x^2-4)^3}$$

Now when I set $f''(x) = 0$, I can't seem to factor the brackets.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Your second derivative isn't correct.

Comment: would you mind showing me the mistake? I have gone over it countless times and can't find it.

Comment: Which method have you used? Would quotient rule be helpful?

Comment: Yes that is the method i used.

Answer (score 1):

You have made a mistake with your second derivative. Lets Apply quotient rule to your first derivative of:

$$\frac{-x^2-6x-4}{(x^2-4)^2}$$

First calculate the derivative of each part.

The derivative of the numerator will be: $-2x-6$

The derivative of the denominator will be: $2(x^2-4)\cdot2x=4x(x^2-4)$

Then applying the quotient rule gives:

$$\frac{(-2x-6)(x^2-4)^2-(-x^2-6x-4)4x(x^2-4)}{(x^2-4)^4}$$

$$=\frac{[x^2-4][(-2x-6)(x^2-4)-(-x^2-6x-4)4x]}{(x^2-4)^4}$$

$$=\frac{-2x^3-6x^2+8x+24+4x^3+24x^2+16x}{(x^2-4)^3}$$

$$=\frac{2x^3+18x^2+24x+24}{(x^2-4)^3}$$

$$=\frac{2(x^3+9x^2+12x+12)}{(x^2-4)^3}$$

This doesn't factorize nicely (one real root involving cube roots and two complex roots also involving cube roots).

EDIT: Compare this to your answer I'm not sure how you got it. You definitely shouldn't have a $x^4$ in the numerator so trace that back to find your mistake.

Comment: ok thanks, but in order to find the inflection points I need to find the x-values. Any suggestions?

Comment: You'd have to use the cubic equation but that is pretty ugly to apply. Did you write the question down correctly? Was it meant to be: $\frac{x+3}{x^2-4}$?

Comment: Thats what i wrote

Comment: The real root comes out as: $x=-3-\sqrt[3]{5}-\sqrt[3]{25}\approx-7.63399\cdots$ but arriving at that is usually beyond the sorts of questions for finding points of inflection. If I may ask what grade/year is this for?

Comment: Alright and Gr. 12 Calculus

Comment: I'd check with your teacher if its actually required as I'd normally say they is beyond the scope of a G12 course. If you have to find the root I'd recommend a quick search for 'cubic formula' for some examples on how to do it, e.g. http://www.sosmath.com/algebra/factor/fac11/fac11.html . If you get stuck trying it just post a new question here at Math.SE. Good luck.